# How to get ID on a specific row in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html

PHP is giving me error of

> Notice: Undefined index: product_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\odieinventory\admin\add_sales.php on line 6

This is my query

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['addCart'])) {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $qtyBuy = $_POST['qtyBuy'];

    $addQuery = "INSERT INTO sales (product_id, quantity) VALUES ($product_id, $qtyBuy)";
    $execQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $addQuery);
  }
?>
```

This is my table

```
<form action="add_sales.php" method="POST">
        <?php 

          $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
          $exec = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {
            $product_id = $row['product_id'];
            $product_name = $row['product_name'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $product_quantity = $row['quantity'];
            $product_price = $row['sell_price'];

         ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product_id; ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $product_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_price; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_quantity; ?></td>

                <td><input type="number" min="1" max="999" name="qtyBuy"></td>
            </tr>
         <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

          <input type="submit" name="addCart" value="Add Items to Cart" class="btn btn-info pull-right">

      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

[image: My Order Page]

I would also like to ask for advice on how to insert records on my cart. By clicking 'Add Items to Cart', I like to pass ONLY the items with values on the quantitiy input on the cart. How to achieve this with PHP?

Comment: If you inspect the hidden element, do you actually see an id in the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: For multiple rows, you will clobber the form data `product_id` with each iteration. It will only ever submit the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table file table.php , you have to:

1- open the `table` and `tbody` HTML tags

2- make your html attributes form name as array (you have more than one input with the same name), in your case you are only submiting the last `product_id` and the last `qtyBuy` input values.

#### table.php

```
<form action="add_sales.php" method="POST">
       <div><table><tbody>
        <?php

          $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
          $exec = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {
            $product_id = $row['product_id'];
            $product_name = $row['product_name'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $product_quantity = $row['quantity'];
            $product_price = $row['sell_price'];

         ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product_id; ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $product_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_price; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product_quantity; ?></td>

                <td><input type="number" min="1" max="999" name="qtyBuy[]"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">

          <input type="submit" name="addCart" value="Add Items to Cart" class="btn btn-info pull-right">

      </div>
</form>
```

In your add_sales.php file, you have to loop the `$_POST['qtyBuy']` variable and check if the given quantity of each product is > 0

#### add_sales.php

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['addCart']) && $_POST['addCart']=="Add Items to Cart") {
     foreach($_POST['qtyBuy'] as $index=>$value){
       if($value > 0){
           $addQuery = "INSERT INTO sales (product_id, quantity) VALUES (".$_POST['product_id'][$index].", ".$value.")";
           $execQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $addQuery);
        }  
     }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I can't upvote your post because I'm new here. I'm also new on PHP. Anyway, do you have any links where to learn foreach? I also saw tutorials on using sessions. Thank you.

Comment: hi you'r welcome --you can take a look here :https://www.codingunit.com/php-tutorial-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should never put users input (`$_POST`) directly into the SQL to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - use [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) with mysqli.

It would be easiest for you to add a separate form with product ID and quantity field and an "Add to cart" button for each product in the table.

Comment: I'll read the links you've given. What do you mean on a seperate form? Can you explain further?

Comment: Well you wold iterate over the rows and inside each `<tr>` you would have a `<form action="...">` for each product. It is not a perfect solution, but a really simple one.